# Implement a function is_repeating_playlist that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not

Tags: python

I am trying to pass al the python tests from testdome.com (https://www.testdome.com/d/python-interview-questions/9)

Question 6 requires you to:

A playlist is considered a repeating playlist if any of the songs contain a reference to a previous song in the playlist. Otherwise, the playlist will end with the last song which points to None.

Implement a function is_repeating_playlist that, efficiently with respect to time used, returns true if a playlist is repeating or false if it is not.

For example, the following code prints "True" as both songs point to each other.

```
first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")

first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(first);

print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

I wrote the following code to check if a song's "next song" points to an earlier song and this works, but the test says I failed 3/4 parts. I am hoping someone can explain why:

```
class Song:
    songs = []
    repeats = []

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.name = name
        self.songs.append(self.name)
        self.next = None

    def next_song(self, song):
        self.next = song

        try:
            self.repeats.append(song.name)

        except(AttributeError):
            self.repeats.append("invalid song")

    def is_repeating_playlist(self):
        """
        :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
        """
        repeats = False

        for i in Song.songs:
            if repeats == True:
                break

            for j in Song.repeats:
                if i == j:
                    print(i,j)
                    print(Song.repeats.index(j), Song.songs.index(i))
                    if Song.repeats.index(i) > Song.songs.index(j):
                        repeats = True
                        break

        return repeats


first = Song("Hello")
second = Song("Eye of the tiger")

first.next_song(second);
second.next_song(first);

print(first.is_repeating_playlist())
```

The code returns True as expected and False if you enter something like  second.next_song("random nonsense);

But clearly more was expected of me?

Comment: The tests describe what they are. Have you tried matching cases?

Answer (score 1):

just use a set and see if you see anything twice

```
def is_repeating_playlist(self):
    """
    :returns: (bool) True if the playlist is repeating, False if not.
    """
    seen = set()
    target = self
    while 1:
        if not target:
            # end of list no cycles found
            return False
        if target in seen:
            # this target has already appeared, so it repeats
            return True
        seen.add(target)
        target = target.next

    return None
```